# golang: garbage collection of tree structure

Tags: recursion, go, tree, garbage-collection

I have a data structure similar to a recursive directory tree, e.g.:

```
type tree struct {
    name string
    subs []*tree
}
```

This data structure is recursive, which means subs can contain tree structures which themselves contains subs, so on and so forth.

Now, with R represents such a tree structure, if I do this: `R.subs = nil`, will the sub-tree items get garbage collected, or I have to write something like this:

```
func (t *tree) Truncate() {
    for _, s := range t.subs {
        s.Truncate()
    }
    t.subs = nil
}
```

In general, my question is how Go knows that some objects are no longer needed and eligible for garbage collection?

thanks a lot.

Comment: "Go compiler" - garbage collection is not the compiler's job. The compiler doesn't have the information needed to make GC decisions.

Comment: sorry about the inaccurate description, I will revise the description.

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/go15gc

Comment: @YandryPozo thanks, after reading that blog post, I think it is not necessary to write such a recursive procedure. Go will take care of the garbage provided there are no "global" pointers to the sub-tree items.

Comment: for the new version 1.8 the time of scanning will be super reduced https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/golang-dev/Ab1sFeoZg_8

Comment: @user2357112 Compilers can make some decisions ahead of time when the lifetime of some data can be determined statically.